# Manipulation of some power series (probably integration or derivation).

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Show that $\ln\Big(|\frac{1+x}{1-x}|\Big)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1},$ for $|x|<1$. The previous excercise (which was within my limited reach) was to show that 
$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n},$ for $|x|<1$. I suspect there is a (not overly subtle) connection here but, needless to say,  I can't see it. I don't know why the absolute value signs are included, but it might be because the solution includes integrating some power series. The excercise is contained in a chapter on derivation and integration of (convergent) power series; one is also assumed to be familiar with multiplication of power series.

Very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$1$. Write down the power series for $\ln(1+x)$.

$2$. Substitute $-x$ for $x$ to find the power series for $\ln(1-x)$.

If you don't know the power series for $\ln(1+x)$, but you probably do, use the power series for $\frac{1}{1+t}$, and the fact that
$\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t}$.  Expand, and integrate term by term.

$3$. We have $\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)$.

The absolute value signs surrounding $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ that you asked about are pointless. Since we are only working with $|x|<1$, the quantity $\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is positive, so the absolute value signs do nothing.

**Some detail:** It is standard that $\frac{1}{1-u}=1+u+u^2+u^3+\cdots$, with the series converging when $|u|<1$. Put $u=-t$. We obtain 
$$\frac{1}{1+t}=1-t+t^2-t^3+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kt^k.$$
It follows that (for $|x|<1$)
$$\ln(1+x)=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t}=\int_0^x\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kt^k  \right)dt=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$
We have now carried out Hint $1$.
Now substitute $-x$ for $x$ in our expression for $\ln(1+x)$. We get 
$$\ln(1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(-x)^{k+1}}{k+1}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$
(The terms $(-1)^k$ and $(-1)^{k+1}$ have product $(-1)^{2k+1}$, which is identically equal to $-1$.) We have now carried out Hint $2$.

Now use Hint $3$. We get 
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left[(-1)^k-(-1)\right]\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}.$$
Consider the coefficient $[(-1)^{k}-(-1)]$ above. This is $2$ if $k$ is even and $0$ if $k$ is odd. To put it another way, we can put $k=2n$, since odd $k$ make no contribution to the sum. Thus
$$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: Well, but using the series for $ln(1+x)$ and $ln(1-x)$ together with $\ln(a/b)=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$, which I had already tried, doesn't yield the deisred identity. I am pretty sure one is supposed to use the sum for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ mentioned above. And the absolute values, pointless though they are, I think may be a hint that one is supposed to integrate both sides of something, since \integral 1/y = ln|y| + C. But I still have no idea how to solve this exercise.

Comment: @Bart Patzer: I wrote out the details. I even used summation symbols, which I don't like to do, since they make things less visually obvious.  The hints (which you will note are essentially the same as those of David Mitra) give the desired expression.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ln{a\over b}=\ln a-\ln b$.

Also, for $|x|<1$:
$$
\ln(1+x)= \phantom{-}x-{x^2\over 2}+{x^3\over3}-{x^4\over 4}+\cdots,
$$
and
$$
\ln(1-x)= -x-{x^2\over 2}-{x^3\over3}-{x^4\over 4}+\cdots .
$$